# Replacing translation result in Laravel 5.7 as a one off?

Tags: laravel, internationalization, translation

Trying to see how it is possible to replace a translation string programmatically in a controlled situation.

e.g. the default i18n has

```
[
    "button": "xxx"
]
```

So when we run `trans('button')` we get back `xxx`

However we're in a situation with a 3rd party package where we need to change this result in a special circumstance, e.g imagine...

```
if (request()->mode === 'create') {
    app('translator')->overwrite('button', 'yyyy');
}
```

So when we do `trans('button')` we get our new `yyyy`

We're not expecting this to persist across pages or anything like that, just a one-off, on the fly change before we get to the view much as you can do `config(['key' => 'new value'])`;

Currently, we have a solution that feels a bit delicate and hacky, that we do not think will work with config caching e.g, so ideally would like a proper solution.

```
return [
    'button' => request()->is('custom-page') ? 'custom text' : 'default text',
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the translation string using the following code:

```
app('translator')->addLines(['form.button' => 'yyyyy'] , 'en');
```

In your case :

```
if (request()->mode === 'create') 
{
   app('translator')->addLines(['form.button' => 'yyyyy'] , 'en');
}
```

Please note that `form` in `form.button` is the name of the language file, so you might need to change it based on your file name.

**Edited**

If you have a namespace then pass the name as third parameter like following:

```
app('translator')->addLines(['form.button' => 'yyyyy'] , 'en', 'your_name_space');
```

Comment: I had tried this, however it removes all the existing loaded translations, our lang was actually within a namespace so was `backpack::form.save_and_edit` or something - wondering if the namespace causes them to reset?

Comment: @Owen. May be. But I am not very sure. Please check the edited part of my answer.